# Change Google Analytics' uniqueness criteria

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics, user-tracking

I am currently using Google Analytics in my Application, where most of the pages are after login. I found an issue with GA, around unique user count. The problem is that if the same user logs in from different machines, then he is tracked as a new user, and if two users login from the same machine, it is tracked as one user. I would like to change the uniqueness algorithm for GA, to use my own accountIds as the unique key. Is this possible? If not, how can I address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Universal Analytics, the new version of GA by generating a unqiue client id per logged in user and passing it to the tracker when it's being created.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'clientId': '35009a79-1a05-49d7-b876-2b884d0f825b'
});
```

(this is an [example from Google  UA Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId), so while I haven't tested this yet I guess it should work).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about UA.

Answer (score 0):

did you try custom variables ? this may be suitable for your situation. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables